# My credit score took a massive dip. Why?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report

I checked my credit score today and it took a massive dip compared to one month ago:

[image]

Ignore the gray line - it's immaterial.

- Transunion - Green
- Experian - Blue
- Equifax - Red

I downloaded the credit report and compared it line by line with the report from last month.  They are exactly identical, except for one thing: my revolving debt went from $16 to $0.

Can someone explain why the score would dip like this and whether there is anything I could do.

Comment: can you tell me from where you are pulling the scores ? and how much you are paying for monthly monitoring of credit score ? Thanks.

Comment: @N30 I am getting the scores from privacyguard.com.  The service is $14.99 and provides the scores as well as the entire report, plus a couple of other handy services.

Comment: Important question: did you simply pay off all of your cards, or did you close them as well? I ask because your followup question indicates that you "no longer had any credit cards".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote [an article about FICO scoring](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/your-fico-score/) which shows that 30% of your score is based on utilization or amount owed. I can't say exactly how much your score will rise, or how long it will take, but your score will improve dramatically from what you propose.

[image: Utilization Chart]

This chart is from Credit Karma, and it shows how zero utilization is actually bad when it comes to your score. I wrote an article on my blog titled [Too Little Debt](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/too-little-debt/) in which I discuss further.
Under 20% is ideal, just not zero.

Comment: The odd thing is that I actually have 2 credit cards (one is a hybrid check card) from Wells Fargo that do have revolving debt, but it doesn't show up on the report.  

I called Wells Fargo and they said that in the case of one card, they only report it when I am delinquent.  And for the other card, they never report it because it just draws on my checking account.

Comment: But you did say the $16 showed on the report, right? Keep in mind, you don't need to pay interest. It's just the month end balance that's causing you grief.

Comment: Credit cards are reported, delinquent or not. Either the OP has a checkcard or the WF rep was clueless

Comment: Are mortgages? Because I am refinancing and my bank told me my mortgage on a rental wasn't showing on my credit report. They got me, the other bank, and Experian on a conference call to request the bank transmit my history to the credit bureau. Strange, but true.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I was speaking from personal experience, which I do not have regarding mortgages. However, I remember that mortgages have a special place/category in Experian (or was it Equifax's?) scoring. Essentially people with mortgages score higher than ones that do not, everything else being equal.

Answer (score 7):

Your case is an excellent example how no credit is scored similar to bad credit.

This curve is nothing unexpected (documented on many sites, including creditkarma) and can be un-done the next reporting period if you maintain at least 1% utilization.

myFICO folks recommend 9% for some reason I have never understood.

Don't worry: if the only reason your credit took a dip is because of your 0% utilization (as you say), it's only a matter of paying for your coffee using that dusty card.

Comment: I don't know about the real models but some of the fake models have a gotcha:  They take the utilization percentage as an integer--I've taken a substantial ding when my utilization dropped below half a percent but was not zero.  (It's actually only current charges showing up, I don't carry balances.)